# How do i perform an api call in php every 5 seconds asynchronously

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm developing a live-score website, and my goal is to refresh an API request every 5 seconds and cache it in (since I only have 1000 requests per hour) and update parts of the website based on the changes of the API every 5 seconds. 

The API request is done in PHP and so is the sorting of the data. However, I've been struggling with implementing the updating part of the API request. I want my API request to update in the background, and some JavaScript to update the website on a 5 second basis so I can get the new data every 5 seconds. 

I would love to get some help. I wanted to do things in CRON, but the host doesn't provide to run CRON every 5 seconds. Any solutions to my problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including the link "How to ask questions the smart way."

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without cron. Something like this would work:

- User's browser sends a request to your API;
- Your API checks if a value exists in cache (Memcached?), if it does - serve from cache;
- If there is no cache entry, your API makes an outgoing request, sorts/processes reply and then caches it with expiration time of 5+ seconds

Advantage as compared to a cron solution - if there are no active users on your website, there are no needless outgoing requests.

You may also consider use of websockets on browser side.

Comment: I actually meant doing an api request to a livescore based api of some company. Caching that data in, and when someone loads the website, it will do a request to the cache every 5 seconds, and if the cache exists longer than 5 seconds, a new api request is done and that data gets cached again. And this basically looping infinitely.

Comment: @SandiKarajic yes, I understood correctly then and my answer is still correct. Unlike 'cron' implementation, my way is on-demand - no users, no load. Got users - got external API requests

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would simply to run the php script in an endless loop rather than trying to run it afresh every 5 seconds.

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

while (true) {
  CacheStuff();
  sleep(5);
}
```

Then trigger it in cron using something like flock to prevent it running more than once.

```
* * * * * flock -n /var/lock/cache_script.lock /path/to/myscript.php
```

Answer (score 0):

**my assumption:**
you dont have any opportunity for cron, memcached, redis etc (basic hosting problem)

**sample**
you can save data to a file as json object.

for example your file name is "5min-data.json"

so your code can be;

```
$timeout_sec = 5;
$file_path = '5min-data.json';
if (file_exists($file_path) && ((filemtime($file_path) - time()) < ($timeout_sec * 60))) {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file_path), true);
}
else {
    //produce your data here as array, it is only sample
    $data = [
        'brand' => 'Mazda',
        'model' => 'Mzd3',
        'year' => 2016,
        'weight' => 1234.5,
        'airbags' => [
            'front-left',
            'front-right',
            'back-left'
        ]
    ];
    file_put_contents ($file_path, json_encode($data));
}
//$data is fresh
```